# Certain characters are not showing up properly when reading HTML source from a webpage in Java

Tags: java, html, character, symbols

I'm going to keep this question short and sweet. I have a function that takes a URL to read as a string and returns a string of the HTML source of a webpage. Here it is:

```
public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception // Returns the source code of a given URL.
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String line;

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        rd.close();

        result.toString();
    }
```

It works like a charm, with the exception of one tiny quirk. Certain characters are not being read correctly by the InputStreamReader. The "ł" character isn't correctly read, and is instead replaced by a "?". That's the only character I've found thus far that follows this behaviour but there's no telling what other characters aren't being read correctly.

It seems like an issue with the character set. I'm using UTF-8 as you can see from the code. All other character sets I've tried using in its place have either outright not worked or have had trouble with far more than just one character.

What kind of thing could be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, what makes you so confident that the response is `UTF-8` encoded?Why not check the connection’s properties to find out which charset the server used?

Comment: @Holger I basically looked through the HTML source and saw `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`. Was I wrong to assume that's UTF-8? I'm still kinda new to this haha.

Comment: Yeah I just confirmed, the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: The content type as reported by the HTTP header (see `HttpURLConnection.getContentType()`) *should* be identical to the content type declared in the HTML page via `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" …`. Since parsers has to assume an encoding in order to get to the HTML tag, using the header is preferred. However, before assuming a broken server, I would check the other end. How do you know that the `String` contains wrong characters? Perhaps, it’s the way you print, display or send the String that can’t handle the character correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: With this, you just tell the server that this requests body is encoded as UTF-8. But GET request has no body.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same charset as the resource you read. First make sure what is the encoding used by that HTML. Usually its content type is sent in response header. You can easily get this information using any web browser with network tracking (since you have GET request).

For example using Chrome - open empty tab, open dev tools (F12), and load desired web page. Than you can look at network tab in dev tools and examine response headers.

Comment: Since this is a site for programmers, calling `getContentType()` on the `HttpURLConnection` object of the question’s code will provide that information without the need to switch the context to another tool like a web browser…

Comment: @Holger Yes, this is a site for programmers. Every programmer should know right tools for a job. Since he is trying to parse (read) HTML page obtained via HTTP protocol, I believe using some advanced HTTP debug tool gives broader insight to problem and its relevant context. Since OP writes he "tried" charsets, I believed this would help him understand the problem better.

Comment: Yeah, checking out the char set in the header was one of the first things I did. It's weird... all other characters are being read correctly from what I can see, with the exception of ł which is read as a "?".

Comment: Well, the thing is that UTF-8 is very similiar to many encodings. I have read it was intentional, but cannot remember the source. Anyway, character ' ł ' is encoded as 2 bytes "C5:82". This is probably why you have a problem with it. Where do you see '?' instead? Console, IDE debugger...? Maybe there is not a problem with reading the character, only its output.

Comment: I'm exporting to a CSV file, and it shows up in both the CSV file when I read it on Excel, and in the IDE's console output. Seems to be an issue with how my program is interpreting the HTML source, because the character shows up just fine if I view the source on my browser.

Comment: Maybe the server does not send correct content-type for the actual HTML file. Browser could show correct formatting by auto select based on the file content instead of relaying on a header. The only way to know for sure is to see actuall content of the source HTML in some hex editor. If it is a public resource, could you provide URL of the page you try to read?